# Double pointer as argument to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to pass a double pointer as argument to a function, but I cant see what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

void changeString(string ***strPtr) {

    strPtr = new string**[1];
    *strPtr = new string*[1];
    **strPtr = new string("hello");
    //cout << strPtr[0][0][0];
}

int main()
{
    string **strPtr;
    changeString(&strPtr);
    //cout << strPtr[0][0];
        return 0;
    }
```

The `cout` in `changeString` works fine, but the `cout` in `main` throws the exception  `read access violation. strPtr was 0xCCCCCCCC.`

Comment: FYI: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: I would rather trust library implementers that they know how to manage memory than myself. There is no reason to dynamically allocate a `std::string`

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. It doesn't matter how many asterisks there are in a parameter's type - assigning a new value to it has no effect outside the function.

Comment: It is just for educational purposes as i want to learn more about how pointers work...

Comment: @HerG You already know much more than you think about how pointers work. If I write down my address on a piece of paper and give it to you, and you write a different address on it instead, I will still be living in the same house as before. On the other hand, if you keep the address and somebody else moves into my house, you won't find me there if you come visiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is basically equivalent to this:

```
void changeString(string **strPtr) {

    strPtr = new string*[1];
    *strPtr = new string("hello");
    //cout << strPtr[0][0];
}

int main()
{
    string *strPtr;
    changeString(&strPtr);
    //cout << strPtr[0];
    return 0;
}
```

And that is basically equivalent to this:

```
void changeString(string *strPtr)
{
    strPtr = new string("hello"); // Changes the pointer, not the string!
    //cout << strPtr[0];
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    changeString(&str);
    //cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

At this point it should start to become obvious that you are assigning a new value to the *pointer*, not the *pointed-to* object. Consider this:

```
void change(SomeType t)
{
  t = somethingElse;
}

int main()
{
  SomeType t;
  change(t); // Does not change t.
}
```

In your case, `SomeType` happens to be `string*` (or `string***`) - you are just overwriting a local variable.

---

To fix your code, just skip the first line in `changeString`:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88874ee3601ef853

```
void changeString(string ***strPtr)
{
    *strPtr = new string*[1];
    **strPtr = new string("hello");
    cout << strPtr[0][0][0];
}

int main()
{
    string **strPtr;
    changeString(&strPtr);
    cout << strPtr[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```